# What is a person called if he likes it when people laugh at him?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a word for a person who likes it when others laugh at him, and make a joke of him?
The sentence for it is like this:

> He is ___, because he liked it when they were making a joke of him

Comment: Does this mean a person who acts in a way to make people laugh (a clown), or just a person who likes it when they do so but does nothing to instigate it?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you are looking for an adjective, how about *self-deprecatory*?**

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-deprecatory) defines the term as:

> expressing disparagement or undervaluation of oneself

and gives the example:

> *But then, in a funny, charming, **self-deprecatory** way he'd start telling rambling, digressive, but observant and intelligent stories that would bare his soul and crack you up …*

This is essentially your proposed situation.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such word in English.

There maybe in other languages. For example, I've heard the term *Schadenfreude* used in English because there no simple word that covers this. It means pleasure gained from another's misfortune. Interestingly it sounds rather like sadist, which was imported from French. Personally, I'm curious as to whether there are any connection between the two.